# C# Epplus - how to sort all data except very first row

Tags: c#, .net, excel, spreadsheet, epplus

I have the following line of code, which sorts data in the worksheet according to specific columns, ascending. The problem is, it takes the very first row into account (cells A1, B1, etc).

```
worksheet.Cells["A:AA"].Sort(new int[] { 5, 10 }, new bool[] { false, false });
```

What `ExcelRange` should I specify in order to take into account only cells below the first row?

Comment: If your sheet has 1000 rows, `Cells["A2:AA1000"]` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard I suppose that will work, since I expect less than 1000 rows in my use case. To do it "properly", though, can I specify no upper limit on the rows somehow?

Comment: If your sheet has 2000 rows, specify 2000. If your sheet has 397 rows, specify... (EPPlus will tell you the end of the sheet - `Worksheet.Dimension.End.Row`)

Comment: Actually I think I managed to solve it, "A2:AA"

Comment: Feel free to post an answer then!

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick:

```
worksheet.Cells["A2:AA"].Sort(new int[] { 5, 10 }, new bool[] { false, false });
```